# Compare MFC CString like MySQL compares

Tags: c++, mysql, mfc, compare, c-strings

MySQL sorts with a comparison operator that is not the same as `CString::CompareNoCase` which has led me to a few hard-to-detect bugs. The main issue seems to be the token `_`.

How can I compare a CString to another one just like MySQL compares strings when using `ORDER BY field`?

Edit:
Could it be that MySQL `ORDER BY BINARY field` uses exactly the same comparison function as `CString::operator<`? My current approach used `SORT BY field` with `CString::CompareNoCase` which have, as described, different comparison operators behind.

Comment: You need to analyze what algorithm MySQL, given your platform and configuration uses, and take it from there. There may not be a pre-implemented solution in `CString` and you may need to provide a custom sort predicate for you application. See [Comparing CString Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b2swax.aspx#_core_comparing_cstring_objects) for built-in comparison functions.

Comment: Writing a custom comparison function is most likely way too slow. Do I have a guarantee for `ORDER BY BINARY` to use some specific operator? And how do I find out?

Comment: [How MySQL Does Sorting (filesort)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/filesort.html).

Comment: I've read the article, it does not state which comparison operator is used

Answer (score 0):

`CString::CompareNoCase()` uses comparison. MySQL uses collation.

Comparison is a strict numerical comparison. Language rules are only used for doing the case conversion. (Doing case conversion will cause you problems in some languages. It's not a great choice.) Collation uses language rules, such as ignoring dashes.

It appears that MySQL has its own built-in collation tables, so there are only two ways to do *exactly* what MySQL does:

- Extract the code from MySQL and use it in your code (Very difficult, and may have licensing issues.)
- Send the strings to the MySQL server and let the server order them for you.

The alternative is to get closer to the MySQL behavior using the collation functions built into Windows. Use `CString::Collate()` instead of `CString::CompareNoCase()`.

You could also use the collation functions built into the open source ICU library if the Windows collation functions don't meet your needs.

Comment: it has to be very performant, so sending anything to the MySQL server will not work. What do you think of `ORDER BY BINARY`?

Comment: Binary what? Utf8? It will work for English. You would need to change the collation order to `utf8_bin` on the MySQL server for all tables where this applies. You will lose case-insensitivity. You will need to re-encode all of your local Unicode strings to utf8 in order to do the comparison.Unfortunately this won't work for most languages, where Unicode solutions like composed characters can cause different byte sequences to mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: okay, but I have english, some extra tokens like dashes, dots, underscores etc. but no other language letters. And I need case sensitivity